# Who shall close Content Provider's cursor?

Tags: android

I'm a little bit confused.

If a `Content Provider` returns a `Cursor` then whose responsibility it is to close that `Cursor`?

On SO there are answers that it is a client responsibility. However, I find it strange because `Cursor` is created outside of a client.

Is it really so that a client shall close `Content Provider`'s `Cursor`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. If the ContentProvider closes the Cursor, then the client won't be able to read from it or use it. The client closes it when finished with it.